# Convert date Python

Tags: python, date

I have `MMDDYY` dates, i.e. today is `111609`

How do I convert this to `11/16/2009`, in Python?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("111609", "%m%d%y")
print date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

This will convert `010199` to `01/01/1999` and `010109` to `01/01/2009`.

Answer (score 0):

```
date = '111609'
new_date = date[0:2] + '/' + date[2:4] + '/' + date[4:6]
```

Comment: Misses the four-digit year part. And what if the date is "010199"?

Comment: The question asked for a 4-figure year, not just the 2 figures from the original string

Comment: Yep. Fail on my part. I only answered because it seemed like the OP wanted a hacked together answer. datetime ftw, imo.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '111609'
>>> d = datetime.date(int('20' + s[4:6]), int(s[0:2]), int(s[2:4]))
>>> # or, alternatively (and better!), as initially shown here, by Tim
>>> # d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m%d%y")
>>> d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
'11/16/2009'
```

one of the reasons why the strptime() approach is better is that it deals with dates close to contemporary times, with a window, i.e. properly handling dates in the latter part of the 20th century and dates in the early part of the 21st century properly.

Answer (score -1):

Incomplete but here's an idea

11/16/2009

```
date_var = ("11/16/2009")    
datetime.date.replace(year=2009, month=11, day=16)
```